# What is the format of the data compressed using zlib and how to uncompress them from command line or other apps?

Tags: c++, qt, compression, zlib, file-extension

I am using [`qCompress()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#qCompress) to compress the data in a file. Now the requirement is that, this file should be un-compressible manually, either via command line or via some standard compression tool.

Since `qCompress()` uses zlib library, what should be the extension of that file (i.e. .zip, .gz, .bz etc)?
Also what kind of *standalone cli* tools should be used to de-compress such files?
(Programmatically we can use [`qUncompress()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#qUncompress)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is scant, but from what I can tell, `qCompress()` writes a four-byte length followed by a zlib stream. There is no file format, extension, nor command line tool for that format. You would have to write your own.

It would be quite straightforward. Just discard the first four bytes, and feed the rest to [zlib](https://zlib.net/) (a C library likely already installed on your machine).

If you are on a Unixish system, you can use `dd` to strip the first four bytes, and then feed the resulting zlib stream to [`pigz -dz`](https://zlib.net/pigz/).

Comment: Got a hint from your answer that, using "zlib.h"'s `::compress2()` would be better than going via `qCompress()` route. Since [`qCompress()`](https://github.com/radekp/qt/blob/master/src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.cpp) is implemented on zlib, it was easier to link it in Ubuntu via `-lz` option. I believe it should work in other platforms too.